# How could I add a css rule to a specific element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add two classes to a div tag. I am using variables with randomized values to calculate the position of the div tags. I don't know how to create a class with these randomized numbers, if it is even possible, could someone help me out?

I don't really know where to start but here's my code

```js
let xValues = []
let yValues = []
let coordinates = []

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  xValues.push(i)
  yValues.push(i)
}
let x1 = xValues[Math.floor(Math.random()*xValues.length)]
let x2 = xValues[Math.floor(Math.random()*xValues.length)]
let x3 = xValues[Math.floor(Math.random()*xValues.length)]
x1 = x1 * 50
x2 = x2 * 50
x3 = x3 * 50
let y1 = yValues[Math.floor(Math.random()*yValues.length)]
let y2 = yValues[Math.floor(Math.random()*yValues.length)]
let y3 = yValues[Math.floor(Math.random()*yValues.length)]
y1 = y1 * 50
y2 = y2 * 50
y3 = y3 * 50

console.log("("+x1+", "+y1+") "+"("+x2+", "+y2+") "+"("+x3+", "+y3+")")
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}
.bg{
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative
}
.obst {
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
#obst1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  left: 450px;
}
#obst2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 200px;
}
#obst3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 300px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="bg">
    <div class="obst" id="obst1"></div>
    <div class="obst" id="obst2"></div>
    <div class="obst" id="obst3"></div>
  </div>
  <button onclick="play()"
  
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

I'm very new to coding as well as stack overflow so if I mess something up I am sorry.

Comment: which div do you want to add the classes into? you need to edit your question and more details on what want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another - shorter - way of doing it:

```js
function rnd(n){
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * n);
}

document.querySelectorAll(".obst").forEach(o=>{
  o.style.top=rnd(200)+"px";
  o.style.left=rnd(200)+"px";
});
```

```css
.obst{ padding: 6px;
       background-color:#fff;
       border: 1px solid #888;
       position: absolute; }
```

```html
  <div>
    <div class="obst" id="obst1">apple</div>
    <div class="obst" id="obst2">orange</div>
    <div class="obst" id="obst3">banana</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This soluttion uses a helper function to generate random values and a [teplate literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to set the text contents of some div elements.

```js
const
  obsts = document.querySelectorAll('.obst'),
  limit = obsts.length,
  xVals = [],
  yVals = [];

// Populates values arrays
for(let i = 0; i < limit; i++){
  xVals.push(getRandoBelow(limit));
  yVals.push(getRandoBelow(limit));
}

// Populates DOM elements
for(let i = 0; i < limit; i++){
  obsts[i].textContent += `x: ${xVals[i]}, y: ${yVals[i]}`;
}

// Generates a random integer below 50
function getRandoBelow(limit){
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);
}
```

```css
.obst{ margin: 0.6em; }
```

```html
  <div>
    <div class="obst" id="obst1">obst1 . . . </div>
    <div class="obst" id="obst2">obst2 . . . </div>
    <div class="obst" id="obst3">obst3 . . .</div>
  </div>
```